# Do adjectives always agree with nouns in gender and number?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

Do all Italian adjectives have to agree with the noun in gender and number? What if you include a color? For example, "a light green car" should be "una macchina verde chiara" but I cannot find any examples of the color verde used with the feminine form of the adjective chiaro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adjectives always have to agree.

The example you mention is actually very good, because it shows a mismatch in this sense.

You have to say

> Una macchina verde chiaro

because *chiaro* here refers to "verde" and not to "macchina". So you need the masculine because of the agreement with verde itself, "verde chiaro" is a composite adjective.

Comment: It may be useful to remember that "verde" (as well as colors in general) is felt as masculine because there's an understated "colore" in there.

Answer (score 3):

In your example the color of the car is "light green", it's like you say "una macchina di color verde chiaro" or more shortly "una macchina verde chiaro".

I think it's simplier to understand with yellow: "una macchina gialla", but "una macchina (color) giallo chiaro".

But you can say "una tonalità (shade) verde chiara" even if "una tonalità (color) verde chiaro" is possible.

Comment: You are missing OP's point, which boils down to: if in "una macchina verde" *verde* is feminine like any other adjective would be (although the declination here doesn't show it), why do you say "una macchina verde chiaro", instead of "una macchina verde chiara"?

Comment: ops, let me try to improve